# Is it possible to find the location of the soft button bars in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-statusbar

I am trying to locate the location of the soft button bar in Android (where instead of hardware back, menu etc. buttons, they are displayed on screen).

I know how to get the actual window size in pixels with something like

```
Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);
d.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

... and then see if the "regular" display metrics compared with the "real" display metrics.
Thus I know if the soft button bar is on the horizontal or vertical position (and how many pixels it is), but I don't know if it is on the left or on the right.

Any ideas how to retrieve that?

**EDIT**: The context of the code is inside an Activity (as asked).

Comment: Are you in an Activity?

Comment: Yes I am in a activity

Comment: On my pixel xl (8.0), the navbar is always positioned towards the  physical bottom of the phone. With a bit of digging, you can see if this is device/version consistent, and then use [`activity.getRequestedOrientation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getRequestedOrientation()) to decipher if the physical bottom is leftmost or rightmost.

Comment: On my LG phone it is always on the left (no matter the orientation) while on the Google Pixel is where the physical bottom is. So this is not consistent.

Comment: [`Display.getRotation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()) is probably what you're looking for. It's also what `NavigationBarView` uses internally to determine how to rotate the nav buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable indicator of where system windows are (such as the status bar and navigation bar) is through the use of system window insets, as explained in the [Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec).

Prior to API 21, this required that your root view of your Activity be a subclass where you've overridden [fitsSystemWindows()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#fitSystemWindows%28android.graphics.Rect%29) - the `Rect` passed to you tells you on which sides and at what sizes the status bar/navigation bar is (depending on what flags you have set on your activity).

However, on API 21+, you can instead do this without creating a custom view by using [`ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener%28android.view.View,%20android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener%29):

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(yourRootView,
    new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
      @Override
      public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
        // Use insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom(), etc to extract
        // the size and location of the system windows
        return ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, insets);
      }
    });
```